# How the Compiler fetch the DLL in Dot Net Work Flow process?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In Dot Net work Process the Compiler Converts the Source code in to IL at the Compiler, In this stage the Compiler get the referenced (eg:. System.dll) DLL from the GAC location initially this wise okay, But if have a custom DLL means it obviously not avail at GAC in this scenario the compiler get these custom DLL from which location. whether it is from the bin or Reference path location.

Comment: the GAC always wins

Comment: @DanielA.White Custom DLL is not avail at GAC then how it fetch these DLL

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I could understand, here is my answer

This depends on how you reference the dll however GAC always wins. Check your project file

System/Assembly/GAC dlls -

```
<Reference Include="System" />
```

Project reference -

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj">
        <Project>{a0f19c44-5e1e-4702-9e2a-256f11058cac}</Project>
        <Name>ClassLibrary1</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
```

DLL reference

```
    <Reference Include="AsyncIO">
        <HintPath>path_to_dll/test.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```